# How do I update text descriptions and URL links in an xml file using a SQL database

Tags: sql, xml, database

Can someone head me in the right direction? I just can't get a clear answer for this , I am sure, ver simple task .I have created a database with images, text strings and links and I want to insert certain cells into an XML file I have that is used in an image flipper of sorts. For example when I automatically update the database I want the xml file to show the new images text and links.

Right now my xml looks like this

```
 <photo image="images/01.jpg" url="http://www.straightapp.com/1.html" target="_blank">        <![CDATA[Download the new<br>Check my first image out]]></photo>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably write a cron or daemon to check for updates to the database table (compare to local storage or set up some kind of trigger from the database if possible), then read in the xml file, append it, and rewrite it.

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but that would be pretty easy.